# How to solve this 2nd-order ODE with singularity?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method, eigenvalues, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I tried solving the eigenvalue problem of a 2nd-order ODE $$[b^2(k-2)^2y^2-2b(k-2)(1+2ky)+4k^2+b^2(k-2)3y]f(y) \\- 3b(3by-2)f'(y)\\-(3by-2)^2f''(y)=\lambda f(y)$$ with `NDEigenvalue`. $b,k$ are just real parameters. Note that the long bracket in front of $f(y)$ is just a quadratic polynomial of $y$. Let's say $b>0$ for simplicity. The boundary condition is Dirichlet at infinity or at least very far away to get a completely decayed convergent solution and here I just use Dirichlet at empirically large enough `yL` and `yR`.
Thanks to @bbgodfrey, who reminded me of a singularity from $(3by_\mathrm{sgl}-2)=0$. I updated much of this post and prefer not showing the very naive old version.

1. It appears from the equation that the singularity renders both the 1st- and 2nd-order derivatives to contribute less and less when approaching ${y_\mathrm{sgl}}-$, *beyond which the solution (possibly??) varies little*.  Numerically, this holds nice when $b$ is small while the turning point will be smoothed and shifted further rightward when $b$ is larger (but why?).
2. Numerically, another important and intriguing finding is that
   **increasing $b$ has the effect of squeezing the solution towards $y_\mathrm{sgl}$**, which is not yet intuitively clear to me.
   *Therefore, the larger $b$ becomes, the more unstable the numerical solution might be, I guess.*
3. But what is ***the solution*** to be squeezed? Actually, a parent and simpler equation is $$[b^2(k-2)^2y^2-2b(k-2)(1+2ky)+4k^2]f(y) \\-4f''(y)=\lambda f(y),$$ whose $n$th solution is basically related to the $n$th [Hermite polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) with $n-1$ node(s). From the figures below, one would tentatively guess that it's this to be squeezed. Rather surprising to me, the node structure looks intact.

When $b$ is small like 0.03, the solution seems probably not that bad. But for larger $b$ like 0.5,1.0 or so, the resultant eigenvalues are very unstable against tuning the `MeshOptions`. Unfortunately, I don't know if there is an analytical solution. So I hope there could be some way around or even other methods to improve or reassure and it certainly also helps if one can somewhat understand the numerical observations.

```
    k = 0; b = 0.03; Nless = 20;
    ysgl = Solve[(-2 + 3 b y) == 0, y][[1, 1]] // Last; yR = 1.3 ysgl; yL = -Sign[b] 7/Sqrt[Abs@b];
    lhs = (b^2 (-2 + k) y (3 + (-2 + k) y) - 2 b (-2 + k) (1 + 2 k y) + 4 k^2) f[y] 
          - (-2 + 3 b y) (3 b D[f[y], y] + (-2 + 3 b y) D[f[y], {y, 2}]);
    bc = DirichletCondition[f[y] == 0, True];
    {vals, funcs} = 
      NDEigensystem[{lhs, bc}, f[y], {y, yL, yR}, Nless, 
       Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" 
        -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01, "MeshOrder" -> 2}}}}];
    vals
```

The `Norm` of first ten solutions plotted when $b=0.03$.[image]
when $b=0.06$[image]

---

### Update of the analytic solution and a puzzling point

It's really nice to have an analytic solution like the one by @bbgodfrey. We can actually first shift $y\rightarrow y+\frac{2}{3b}$ in the ODE. Then the singularity $y_\mathrm{sgl}=0$. The solution is $f(y)=\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{3}(k-2)y}y^{\frac{\Delta}{9b}}u(y)$ where $\Delta=\sqrt{16(k+1)^2-9\lambda}$ and $u$ is polynomial.

**However**, the exponential factor in $f(y)$ will *diverge* on the right of $y_\mathrm{sgl}$. **It looks that analytic solution doesn't allow a physical solution vanishing at $+\infty$**, although it's good if one sets Dirichlet b.c. exactly at $y_\mathrm{sgl}$. *But I would expect a solution even for $y>y_\mathrm{sgl}$.* If not, this is really surprising since the original physical meaning of y is merely a coordinate in $(−\infty,+\infty)$, not anything like a radius defined in $(0,+\infty)$.

On the other hand, **the numerical solution always looks vanishing for $y>y_\mathrm{sgl}$**. From the analytic solution, @bbgodfrey claims an upper bound of eigenvalues and higher ones are spurious. What I observe in numerics is twofold. For those 'good' eigenvalues, $f(y_\mathrm{sgl})=0$ seems sharp. For those 'spurious' eigenvalues, $f(y_\mathrm{sgl})=0$ or a turning point seems smoothed. I really have no idea if numeric solution for $y>y_\mathrm{sgl}$ is just an artifact or anything else.

Comment: What are your boundary conditions? Do you want it to decay towards infinity in both directions? You have $b$ and $k$ in your equation, is one the eigenvalue and one a parameter? As you assign values to both.

Comment: Actually, the ODE is singular at `(-2 + 3 b y) == 0`, and this is the source of your problem, I believe.,

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks a lot for correcting me! Updated with more efforts.

Comment: @KraZug Updated with more efforts and details. Yes, decay towards infinity in both directions. $b,k$ just parameters.

Comment: Ugh, I hate that NDEigensystem requires to only give the left hand side of the equation, which seems so counter to everything else in Mathematica.

Comment: In my experience, if this question derives from a physical problem, then the singularity suggests that some otherwise small term cannot be ignored in the vicinity of the singularity, and adding it eliminates the singularity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ODE itself can be solved symbolically.  For generality, assume that `k` and `b` are undefined and that `ll` is the unknown eigenvalue.  Then,

```
s = DSolveValue[lhs == ll f[y], f[y], y] // Simplify
(* E^(-(((-2 + k) (-2 + 3 b y))/(9 b))) (-6 + 9 b y)^(Sqrt[16 + 32 k + 16 k^2 - 9 ll]/(9 b)) 
   (C[1] HypergeometricU[(-4 + 9 b - 4 k + Sqrt[16 + 32 k + 16 k^2 - 9 ll])/(9 b), 
    1 + (2 Sqrt[16 + 32 k + 16 k^2 - 9 ll])/(9 b), (2 (-2 + k) (-2 + 3 b y))/(9 b)] + 
    C[2] LaguerreL[-((-4 + 9 b - 4 k + Sqrt[16 + 32 k + 16 k^2 - 9 ll])/(9 b)), 
    (2 Sqrt[16 + 32 k + 16 k^2 - 9 ll])/(9 b), (2 (-2 + k) (-2 + 3 b y))/(9 b)]) *)
```

To proceed, apply the boundary condition that the solution vanishes at `y == 2/(3 b)`.  A bit of numerical experimentation indicates that `C[1] -> 0` is required, substantially simplifying `s`.  The second boundary condition is that the solution vanishes for large negative `s`.  Again, some numerical experimentation indicates that the first argument of `LaguerreL` must be a non-negative integer, which determines the eigenvalues.

As a specific example, consider the first set of parameters in the question.

```
s /. C[1] -> 0 /. {k -> 0, b -> 3/100}
(* E^(200/27 (-2 + (9 y)/100)) (-6 + (27 y)/100)^(100/27 Sqrt[16 - 9 ll])
   C[2] LaguerreL[-(100/27) (-(373/100) + Sqrt[16 - 9 ll]), 
   200/27 Sqrt[16 - 9 ll], -(400/27) (-2 + (9 y)/100)] *)
```

Setting the first argument of `LaguerreL` to an integer yields

```
Solve[-(100/27) (-(373/100) + Sqrt[16 - 9 ll]) == n, ll, Integers] // Flatten
(* {ll -> ConditionalExpression[(2319 + 2238 n - 81 n^2)/10000, 
   (n | (2319 + 2238 n - 81 n^2)/10000) \[Element] Integers && n <= 13]} *)
```

So, there are only 14 eigenvalues, namely

```
Table[{n, (-3 (-773 - 746 n + 27 n^2))/10000}, {n, 0, 13}]
(* {{0, 2319/10000}, {1, 1119/2500}, {2, 6471/10000}, {3, 519/625}, {4, 399/400}, 
    {5, 2871/2500}, {6, 12831/10000}, {7, 876/625}, {8, 15039/10000}, {9, 159/100}, 
    {10, 16599/10000}, {11, 1071/625}, {12, 17511/10000}, {13, 4431/2500}} *)
```

These values agree well with the first fourteen eigenvalues given in the question.  (The rest of the numerical eigenvalues in the question are spurious.)  The plot of the eigenfunction corresponding to the largest eigenvalue is, for example,

```
coef = s /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1} /. {k -> 0, b -> 3/100}
    /. ll -> 4431/2500 /. y -> 0
Plot[Evaluate[s/coef /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1} /. {k -> 0, b -> 3/100} 
    /. ll -> 4431/2500], {y, -40, 200/9}, PlotPoints -> 1000, 
    ImageSize -> Large, AxesLabel -> {y, f}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

(The magnitude of `coef` is arbitrary, but its phase causes the function to be real, allowing it to be plotted.)

[image]

**Addendum: Special case of k = 2**

A number of comments on this page are associated with the question of whether eigenvalues exist for `ll > 16 (k + 1)^2 /9`.  After substantial analysis, I am confident that there are none.  To illustrate, consider the particularly simple case, `k = 2`. which has no eigenvalues at all, despite the fact that `NDEigensystem` asserts their existence.

```
Clear[b, k];
lhs = (b^2 (-2 + k) y (3 + (-2 + k) y) - 2 b (-2 + k) (1 + 2 k y) + 4 k^2) f[y]
    - (-2 + 3 b y) (3 b D[f[y], y] + (-2 + 3 b y) D[f[y], {y, 2}]);
lhs /. k -> 2
DSolve[% == ll f[y], f[y], y] // Flatten

(* 16 f[y] - (-2 + 3 b y) (3 b f'[y] + (-2 + 3 b y) f''[y]) *)
(* {f[y] -> C[1] Cos[(Sqrt[-16 + ll] Log[-2 + 3 b y])/(3 b)] + 
            C[2] Sin[(Sqrt[-16 + ll] Log[-2 + 3 b y])/(3 b)]} *)
```

For `ll > 16`, neither the `Sin` nor the `Cos` term vanish at large negative `y`. And the two terms clearly cannot cancel, so the large negative `y` boundary condition cannot be satisfied.  Moreover, `f[y]`oscillate every faster as `y` approaches, `2/(3 b)`, which also is not acceptable.  Nonetheless, `NDEigensystem`, employed as in the question (but with `yR = ysgl` to avoid integrating through the singularity, and `b = 1/10`), predicts eigenvalues

```
(* {29.0571, 30.6642, 33.1095, 36.353, 40.3784, ...} *)
```

The eigenfunction corresponding to the first eigenvalue is

```
Plot[First@funcs, {y, yL, yR}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {y, f}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

[image]

Simply stated, numerical methods typically do not handle singularities well.  For completeness, consider `ll < 16`.

```
lhs /. k -> 2;
Collect[DSolve[% == ll f[y], f[y], y, Assumptions -> (ll < 16)] // 
    Flatten // TrigToExp, Power[(2 - 3 b y), _], Simplify] /. 
    {(C[1] - I C[2]) -> 2 C[3], (C[1] + I C[2]) -> 2 C[4]}

(* {f[y] -> (2 - 3 b y)^(-Sqrt[16 - ll]/(3 b)) C[3] + 
            (2 - 3 b y)^( Sqrt[16 - ll]/(3 b)) C[4]} *)
```

A bounded solution as `y` approached `2/(3 b)` requires `C[3] = 0`, and a bounded solution as `y` approaches `-Infinity`requires `C[4] = 0`.  No eigenvalues here either.

Finally, note that the leading terms from

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[lhs == ll f[y], f[y], {y, 2/(3 b), 1}, 
    Assumptions -> (y < 2/(3 b))]

(* (-(2/(3 b)) + y)^(Sqrt[16 + 32 k + 16 k^2 - 9 ll]/(9 b)) C[1] +
   (-(2/(3 b)) + y)^(-Sqrt[16 + 32 k + 16 k^2 - 9 ll]/(9 b)) C[2] *)
```

also oscillate ever faster as `y` approaches `2/(3 b)` when `ll > 16 (k + 1)^2 /9`, which is unacceptable for an eigenfunction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I want to ask if there's any mathematical argument for taking the b.c. as vanishing at the singular point. Is it standard practice? Only by looking at the numerical solutions, this is not exactly fulfilled. But this might just be an artifact?

Comment: @xiaohuamao  Taking the boundary condition at the singularity to be zero is not necessary.  In fact, you can choose whatever boundary condition you wish.  It all depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  I perhaps should have said that, of the two independent solutions, I chose the one that was not singular there.  In fact, if you choose the smaller of the two solutions at the singular point, even if it too is singular, you obtain more eigenvalues.

Comment: Let me confirm. You mean `HypergeometricU` is singular there, right? BTW, your two important numerical-experimentation indications are valid for general $k,b$, right? Not for special ones like $k=0$.

Comment: @xiaohuamao  Numerical experimental cannot be exhaustive, and my analysis certainly was not.  I can, however, say with confidence that one solution is, itself, singular at the singular point, and the other vanishes there.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, I can get good agreement with these eigenvalues when I apply the same bcs via the Evans function method, but they continue to be regularly spaced after that.

Comment: @KraZug Interesting. Could you provide a few of the larger eigenvalues?  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. Note that the eigenvalues of the matrix system (z'=Az) at the singularity change from real to complex at $\lambda=16/9$, which all your eigenvalues are below. If I put the right endpoint at `ysgl-0.0001`, then $1.7791, 1.7837, 1.79061$ are my next three. If I put it at `ysgl-0.00001`, then $1.78118, 1.78547, 1.79109$.

Comment: Although as I push the right endpoint closer and closer to `ysgl` I can't guarantee that they are not coalescing or entirely spurious.

Comment: I’m not sure if I’m being silly. But I think there’s still a gap regarding your ‘LaguerreL’ solution. Noticing the exponential factor in front, we know it’s divergent on the right of $y_{\mathrm{sgl}}$. However, the numerical solution always looks perfectly vanishing, or all of them are partially spurious? I still couldn’t figure out how to get the corresponding analytical solution. This question is because I think a bc on the right of the singularity is physically plausible. @KraZug Have you tried the region on the right of the singularity?

Comment: @xiaohuamao  You should not try to integrate through the singularity.  Symbolic solutions are not continuously differentiable there, so there is no rigorous way to connect solutions on each side, and numerical methods yield dubious results.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum! I think tentatively the remaining question is whether a solution exists for $(y_\mathrm{sgl},+\infty)$. If not, this really surprises me from my very limited experience of special function/ODE, since the original physical meaning of $y$ is merely a coordinate in $(-\infty,+\infty)$, not something like a radius defined in $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @xiaohuamao  I imagine that solutions for `y > ysgl` also exist, depending on the boundary conditions chosen.

Comment: But the exponential factor in the general analytical solution doesn't seem to allow a physical solution vanishing at $+\infty$? That's what puzzles me.

Comment: @xiaohuamao  You may well be correct.

Comment: xiaohuamao, I can't integrate through the singularity with my method. @bbgodfrey, I do think that the additional potential solutions I'm seeing to the right of $16 (k + 1)^2 /9$ are spurious.